# How to ask multiple computers by ssh through the same command

Tags: command-line, ssh

```
computer1:~$ ssh -p 2222 computer2@192.x.x.x 'who -b' | \
> awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
```

This code help me figure out when computer2 last booted and puts the information in a textfile named textfile.txt. 
But what if i want to ask computer2 AND a computer3 the same thing in the same command and then puts the information in the textfile? How do i ask multiple computers in the same command?

Thanks!

Comment: @dessert nope. The IP will be different ;) btw: Ludvig Gällstedt computer2 and  computer3  are users not systems,

Comment: @Rinzwind Oh of course, so `for i in user1@host1 user2@host2; do ssh $i … ; done` is the right approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You repeat the question:

```
ssh -p 2222 computer2@192.x.x.100 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
ssh -p 2222 computer2@192.x.x.101 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
```

The ">>" will append it to "textfile.txt".

---

If you put the IP addresses in a text file you can loop through it (pseudo example):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='ipaddresses.txt'
while read p; do 
    ssh -p 2222 $p 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
done < $filename
```

Comment: `pssh` might help as well, although I'm not sure about parsing the output for OP's needs.

Answer (score 2):

Create a script and run that:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -p 2222 user@192.x.x.10 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
ssh -p 2222 user@192.x.x.11 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> textfile.txt
```

Don't for get to `chmod +x myscript.sh` to make it executable.

You are going to need key based authentication setup as well, a script won't easily handle password challenges.